# Backend error - Magento 2.4.2p1

Tags: magento2, error, backend

we finished migration and we got an issue after loging to backend. I see dashboard, but I cannot handle anything (icons on the left side in admin look like inactive)

This is screen of the issue: https://prnt.sc/15pn9gk

I have Magento 2.4.2-p1

Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thank you very much.

V.

Comment: Did you find that file in that location? Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f command and see.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work...:-(

Comment: Have you checked if the file is in the file system (in pub/static and where the url expects it to be) and if it has the correct owner/permissions on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands

```
 rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*

 php bin/magento setup:upgrade

 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work as well :-(